# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Not able to connect external monitor using HDMI

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have HP Probook 450 G8 notebook with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed.
Whenever I try to connect to second monitor using HDMI, the display settings is kind of refreshed, suddenly losing the second monitor option to vanish and come back again. My second monitor detects the signal but suddenly laptop gets back to primary monitor. Although it gives option to Save changes or Revert, but that's of no use.

I tried sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, it says "All the available drivers are already installed"

Laptop Specs:
Graphics: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT@)
CPU : 11th Gen intel core i5-1135G7

Answer (score 1):

`Right click Desktop > Display Settings`

Verify your monitor is listed and Mirror Displays is not checked

[image]

Comment: Hey, It does show my external display but somehow after joining displays it switches back to built in display. I have a dedicated button in laptop for screen joining/mirroring. I use to get started and later from settings I change the alignments of displays. Till now I did not find what causes this issue.